# Angularjs retain local variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory like this:

```
TestFactory= function () {
    var objectName=null;

    return {
        SetName:function(name) {
            objectName = name;
        },
        GetName:function() {
            return objectName;
        },
        Init:function() {
            return angular.copy(this);
        }
    }
}
```

A controller like:

```
TestController = function($scope) {
    $scope.TestClick = function () {

        var tstA = TestFactory.Init();
        var tstB = TestFactory.Init();

        tstA.SetName('test A')
        tstB.SetName('test B')

        console.log('A', tstA.GetName());
        console.log('B', tstB.GetName());

    }   
}
```

In the console I get `Test B` for both objects.

How can I make a proper instance of this object?

I would like to use the `objectName` value in other functions of the factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take into account that in Angular,  Factories are singletons, so the instance is always the same.

You can do the following:

```
TestFactory= function () {
    var objectName={};

    return {
        SetName:function(property,name) {
            objectName[property] = name;
        },
        GetName:function(property) {
            return objectName[property];
        },
        Clear:function(property) {
            delete objectName[property]
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
TestController = function($scope, TestFactory) {
    $scope.TestClick = function () {

        TestFactory.SetName('a','test A')
        TestFactory.SetName('b','test B')

        console.log('A', TestFactory.GetName('a')); // test A
        console.log('B', TestFactory.GetName('b')); // test B

    }   
}
```

Comment: so I need to tell each consequent function witch key to watch so to speak
would work but not happy with the solution :)

Comment: I accepted this cos it is the closest as it gets. Just for people that come around to this. Please find a way around this requirement. I ended up passing an object with all the relevant data into each consecutive function call of the factory that way I do not have the need for the above. Since it is kinda not the 'Angular way'

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues.  First your returning an object rather than a function from your factory.

```
app.factory('TestFactory', function() {
  return function() {
    var objectName = null;

    var setName = function(name) {
      objectName = name;
    };

    var getName = function() {
      return objectName;
    };

    return {
      SetName: setName,
      GetName: getName
    };
  };

});
```

Then you can just instantiate like this:

```
var tstA = new TestFactory();
var tstB = new TestFactory();
```

Answer (score 1):

Services and factories are singletons so I think you can achieve what you want with a more appropriate use of the factory by providing an `Init` function that returns the common code and unique name like so:

```
angular.module('app')
       .factory('ServiceFactory', serviceFactory);

function serviceFactory() {
    return {
        Init: function (name) {
            return {
                objectName: name,
                setName: function (name) {
                    this.objectName = name;
                },
                getName: function () {
                    return this.objectName;
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

This leaves the possibility to use it as a factory that can initialize many types.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to create a simple getter/setter.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('TestController', testController)
  .service('serviceFactory', serviceFactory);


testController.$inject = ['serviceFactory'];

function testController(serviceFactory) {

  serviceFactory.set('A', {
    name: 'test A'
  });

  serviceFactory.set('B', {
    name: 'test B'
  });

  console.log(serviceFactory.getAll());
  console.log(serviceFactory.get('A'));
  console.log(serviceFactory.get('B'));

}

function serviceFactory() {
  var 
  _model = {
    name: ""
  },
  _data = {};

  return {
    set: function(key, data) {
      _data[key] = angular.extend({}, _model, data);
    },
    get: function(key) {
      return _data[key];
    },
    getAll: function() {
      return _data;
    }
  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="testController"></body>
```